# ¿Cómo se dice: "morriña" o "modorra"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, palabras-raras

Muchas veces, para indicar que les está entrando sueño, oigo a la gente decir:

> ¡Buf! Me está entrando una *morriña*...

Yo creía que la palabra que se usaba para eso era "modorra". Es decir que sería:

> ¡Buf! Me está entrando una *modorra*...

¿Qué es lo correcto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo correcto es **modorra**.

Es cierto que hay gente que utiliza *morriña* en ese sentido, pero según la RAE la palabra adecuada es:

> **[modorro, rra](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=PV9CZFy)**.
>
> 5. f. **Somnolencia**, **sopor** profundo.
> 6. f. **Sueño** muy pesado y, a veces, patológico.

Mientras que:

> **[morriña](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=morri%C3%B1a)**.
>
> Del gallegoportugués *morrinha*.
>
> 1. f. coloq. Tristeza o melancolía, especialmente la nostalgia de la tierra natal.

Entonces, la frase *"me está entrando morriña"* lo que dice es que te estás empezando a sentir triste o nostálgico.

La palabra la hemos cogido del gallego porque era la que usaban, para decir que echaban de menos su tierra, [decenas de miles de emigrantes gallegos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inmigraci%C3%B3n_gallega_en_Argentina) que tuvieron que dejar Galicia a finales del s. XIX y principios del s. XX.

Así que, salvo que te pongas triste cuando te da sueño (lo cual suele pasar cuando hay vino de por medio)... **lo correcto es usar *modorra***, no *morriña*.

Comment: La morriña vendría a ser la _saudade_ portuguesa.

Comment: @fedorqui *saudade* también existe en gallego

Comment: curioso, está en el DRAE también: http://dle.rae.es/?id=XM6WldQ

Comment: Perdonad mi incultura o vulgaridad , yo siempre me he dicho a morriña para referirme a sueño en forma diminutiva y modorra en aumentativa . Visto lo visto lo mio es dar patadas a la RAE .

Answer (score 1):

Conozco ambos términos, morriña y modorra, en algunos pueblos de Andalucía como por ejemplo Ferreira, que fueron repoblados con gallegos, cuando la reconquista, se utilizan muchos galicismos, como pingando por ejemplo, y aún así se usan ambos para definir al sopor previo al sueño, entonces antes de llamar inculta a la gente por no coincidir con la RAE, tened en cuenta que la RAE escribe güisqui y se supone que debe de recoger los diversos usos que tiene una palabra en Castellano, puesto que el gallego también es español y eso sería otro hilo,la cuestión,no tacheis de inclutos a quienes usan una palabra de modo distinto al vuestro, que la cultura implica conocer, en lugar de juzgar...

Comment: Es difícil distinguir lo poco que hay de respuesta en esta contribución de la queja/reflexión. Hay una razón por la que la RAE admite "güisqui" aparte de ["whisky"](https://dle.rae.es/whisky). Cierto es también que la RAE ha terminado por admitir ["almóndiga"](https://dle.rae.es/alm%C3%B3ndiga?m=form) y ["murciégalo"](https://dle.rae.es/murci%C3%A9galo), pero el DRAE los documenta como _vulgarismos_. También la gente dice "te _heristes_" en lugar de "te heriste". A todo se nos ha escapado un "haiga" o un "conducí", pero eso no los hace automáticamente válidos.

Comment: ¿Quién ha "llamado inculta a la gente"? No encuentro ninguna mención de esa palabra en las otras respuestas.

Comment: @Diego solo un detalle. No es que la RAE haya "terminado por admitir _almóndiga_ y _murciégalo_", es que llevan presentes en el diccionario desde el _Autoridades_ del siglo XVIII. De hecho por entonces ninguna de las dos era un vulgarismo.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque su definición más extendida es de "melancolía nostálgica", se usa el coloquialismo «me está entrando una *morriña*» así en algunos dialectos del sur y Las Canarias.<sup>1 2 3 4</sup>

Un otro ejemplo de [malapropismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropismo) es [*vituperio*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=vituperio) en Chile con el significado de "Fiesta o reunión informal con comida o bebida".

---

<sup>1. https://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=2439175</sup>
<sup>2. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/morri%C3%B1a.586224/#post-3279251</sup>
<sup>3. http://foro.capitalsim.net/viewtopic.php?f=120&t=18799&start=15</sup>
<sup>4. https://debates.motos.coches.net/discussion/139033/quiero-una-chica-motera/p623</sup>